# Binding DataGrid control selected items to Command in View Model?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, command, viewmodel

I am trying to take the currently selected objects (rows) in a `DataGrid` control and send them directly to the View Model (MVVM pattern) without any code in the XAML code behind, using `ICommand`.

I have done this with a Button since `ButtonBase` implements the Command property - the `DataGrid` does not. It appears that using Commands between the View and the View Model when using buttons is the convention, but what about other controls?

Is there a way to take the currently selected items and send this in a Command to the View Model?

Answer (score 0):

Here's [an article on the subject](http://silverlightfeeds.com/post/2058/Handling_DataGrid.SelectedItems_in_an_MVVM-friendly_manner.aspx). It's about Silverlight, but the guidance should be useful for WPF as well. Basically it says to use something like EventToCommand (from MVVMLight Toolkit) to translate the `SelectionChanged` event into an ICommand.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the code found [here](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/attachedcommandbehavior-aka-acb/). It is some AttachedProperties which let you hook up Commands to just about any Event

```
<DataGrid
    local:CommandBehavior.Event="MouseDown" 
    local:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"
    local:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
```